# why the value of static member variable is not being assigned to the non- static member variable through this function?

Tags: c++, static, variable-assignment

In the following C++ code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

class Account{
    string *holder;
    enum acc_type{savings, current};
    acc_type account_type;
    static long long int num;

public :
    long long int acc_no = 33527625000;
    long int balance;
    void new_acc(string, int, long int);
    void deposit(int);
    void withdraw(int);
    void display();
};
long long int Account::num;

void Account::new_acc(string x, int type = 1, long int bal = 0)
{
    holder = &x;
    cout<<"@@@@@@@@@@"<<acc_no<<endl;
    acc_no = num;
    cout<<"@@@@@@@@@@"<<acc_no<<endl;
    balance = bal;
    num++;
}
```

The value of `num` is not being assigned to `acc_no` when the function `new_acc` is being called through an object.
Does the function `new_acc` has something wrong in it?

Comment: Once you make this non-example compile, it prints 1. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/R4Jnv2lsJK4LUdso

Comment: You missed a `;` to end your class declaration, which should be declared with the keyword `class` and not `Class`. `Xy::n` is uninitialized, you should write `int Xy::n = 0;`.

Comment: @wasthishelpful this is a static variable, it gets zero-initialized by default

Comment: @wasthishelpful "Xy::n is unitialized`. No, it is intialized to zero.

Comment: @krzaq It's initialized by default, are you sure it is zero-initialized for all compilers ? Is that part of the standard ?

Comment: @wasthishelpful yes

Comment: @krzaq Ok, my bad ^^

Comment: if you just created an object of Xy in main and calls new_a() then it will be as you expected.

Comment: In a similar program, I wrote this code :

` #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>


using namespace std;

class Account{
    string *holder;
    static long long int num;
public :
    long long int acc_no = 33527625000;
    void new_acc(string);
};
long long int Account::num;

void Account::new_acc(string x)
{
    holder = &x;
    cout<<"\n"<<acc_no<<endl;
    acc_no += num;
    cout<<"\n"<<acc_no<<endl;
    num++;
}`

 You can try this one out. This was the real program.

Comment: @krzaq while it it initialised to 0, it's also not a fantastic habit to get into; and I would actively discourage people new to programming to depend on features like that, especially with objects as T x; and T x() are different in this regard.

Comment: I agree that this may bea bad habit, I just pointed out an incorrect statement. Btw, `T x` and `T x()` are exactly the same thing for static variables, unless you hit the most vexing parse - which wouldn't happen here.

Comment: @Sudeep Don't put long codes in comments. Edit the question and show the real code.

Comment: @Sudeep you should edit your question with that program. That being said, there's no assignment of `num` to `acc_no`. You're ADDING it.